# Laravel 6 upload_max_filesize , i just want to upload 5mb file size

Tags: php, laravel, web, localhost

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'thumbnail' => 'max:5048',
        ]);
```

Thats my validatior, i just wanna upload 5mb file.. it is always said error ! help me please ? :")

Its still localhost btw..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation seems correct. You will also need to increase the maximum post file and also upload size of php.

Please updates this values on your php.ini file.

```
upload_max_filesize = 5M
post_max_size = 5M
```

Comment: im sorry sir im newbie, where is the php.ini file ?

Comment: still The file "artikel seo.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).

Comment: are you using linux, windows ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'thumbnail' => 'file|max:5048',
]);
```

Make sure to tell Laravel that it's a file it should compare the max file size against.

Use the description of the [size rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-size) as reference.

Comment: The file "artikel seo.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).

Comment: It might've helped to add the exact error message to your post. [@Vidals answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60935838/8394877) is the correct one.

Comment: Where is the php.ini location ?

Comment: Depends on which OS you operate. A quick Google search will do.

Comment: Still The file "artikel seo.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver?